# Functional Notation Confusion

Tags: functions, notation

This is a fairly basic question but I still can't seem to wrap my head around it, so any help would be appreciated.

In my homework, I have seen this functional notation being used:

$$\ln(1-n)$$

I am confused on what this means, because usually I am more familiar with functional notation like this:

$$f(n) = \ln n$$

So would that mean the $1-n$ in the first expression used is an input into the $\ln n$ function? Like so:

$$f(1-n) = \ln(1-n) = \text{constant}$$

Please let me know as I believe I'm interpreting it wrong.

Comment: I came here from your [meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33075/can-i-post-a-homework-question-without-any-mathjax-latex?cb=1) and I'm happy with the presentation of this question. +1, and if you find this post prettier than the work you must have done in your notebook, I'm sure you will feel more comfortable typing in MathJax in the future. Please do not hesitate in comments to ask for help from other users in cleaning up any doubts you have on your presentation and how you can make it better. This post was very good.

Comment: Thanks a lot Teresa!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\ln(1-n)$ is shorthand for the following calculation:

Suppose you have a number called $n$ take for example $0.1$.

You compute $1-n$, this would be $1-0.1 = 0.9$.

Then you compute the logarithm of that number. So in this case $\ln(1-n) = \ln(1-0.1) = \ln 0.9 $ $= -0.10536051565$.

If your book defines a function using $f(n) = \ln(1-n)$ they mean it maps a number $n$ to $\ln(1-n)$.

Comment: I see, so could I ask how a derivative could be taken of that function?

Comment: A derivative of $\ln(1-n)$ can be taken by applying the chain rule. You differentiate the logarithm, then multiply this by the derivative of what's inside the logarithm. So $\ln'(1-n) \times (1-n)'$.

Comment: Thanks for replying! So would it be correct to interpret it as a function within a function, say $f(n(m))$? So then we would need to take the derivative of $f$ wrt $m$, and then $m$ wrt to $n$ (ie. the chain rule)?

Comment: Yes, that is correct! It is the combination of two functions namely $\ln: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: x \mapsto \ln(x)$ and $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: x \mapsto 1-x$.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

The variable $n$ in the expression $f(n)=\ln(n)$ is a "dummy variable"; this $n$ is different from the $n$ in $\ln(1-n)$.

You can write your function as $f(m)=\ln(m)$, and interprets $\ln(1-n)$ as the value of the function $f$ evaluated at $m=1-n$.

Alternatively, $\ln(1-n)$ is the [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition) $f\circ g$ of the function $f(n)=\ln(n)$ and the function $g(n)=1-n$.

Comment: would that be a function within a function then? Ie. $f(n(m))$?

Comment: In the function composition interpretation: $\ln(1-n)=f\circ g(n)=f(g(n))=\ln(g(n))$.

Comment: Ah I see, sorry for the confusing choice of notation! Yours make more sense.